# Why does SiC have lower Rds(on) than GaN?

Tags: gan, sic

It seems that GaN has higher Rds(on) than SiC.

The lowest Rds(on) that I found for a 650 V GaN is 25 mΩ @ 25°C. SiC has even lower resistance @ 1200 V like 16 mΩ @ 25°C.

Does anyone know the physical reason? Does it mean that GaN can provide better efficieny due to its better switching parameter? Obviously it means that GaN at low swicthing frequency is worse than SiC.

Comment: Relative to what? Is it just the biggest devices you found for sale? The reason is that's what they're selling. :shrug:

Comment: I do not get it ? In general for the same voltage rating, the rds(on) is higher for GaN than for SiC

Comment: In what general? If I were to show you one GaN part rated 50mΩ and another SiC part rated 200mΩ, what would you say?

Comment: I took the lowest Rds(on) that I found with GaN and I saw that SiC was better. I think that SiC is better than GaN for rds(on) vs voltage rating. But if you find me a lower Rds(on) for GaN @ 650V @ 25°C, i will be wrong

Comment: The higher bandgap voltage of GaN compared to Si (and SiC) means that for the same design voltage, a GaN device can be thinner which means lower resistance.

Comment: Rds(on) is just one aspect of the balancing-act.  If any one aspect is improved, then other aspect(s) will worsen.  Must look at *all of the parameters* simultaneously to determine if one device is better than another *for that application*.

Comment: Ok so you did literally search for the lowest Rds(on) at a given supplier (or perhaps several suppliers, or across manufacturers, I don't know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest (lowest Rds(on), highest Qg, etc.) devices available at a distributor, or from manufacturers, is literally just what they happen to have on hand, or on offer, and at best reflects market trends; there's little if anything fundamental about the chips themselves.

Another possibility you might not've considered: yield.  Particularly among newer semiconductors, defect rate or process yield may be poor.  As I recall, SiC wafers have a certain density of screw defects, the most pernicious kind in the material; if a transistor happens to fall on a location with too many of these, it may be rejected.  There is thus pressure to reduce device size to maximize yield.  As defects get ironed out of the wafer-production process, maximum economical chip size will likewise grow.

I don't know the stats for modern GaN processes (usually epitaxial over buffer layers over Si), but there may be similar size or yield limitations due to the behavior of that process.

For reference, the yield limit for standard Si is around 1-2cm, where the limitation is not so much process yield (after the better part of a century's collective industry experience, they're *very* good at working with Si), but packaging limitations: the chip can't be bonded to a reasonable substrate (like Cu) without enduring excessive stress due to thermal expansion.

As far as I know, the chips in SiC and GaN devices are *extraordinarily* small, in comparison to Si devices of similar ratings; their performance really is just that good.  (It also shows off SiC's great thermal conductivity, that similar power ratings in a TO-247 can be had from a die a fraction of the size!)

---

There are still other limitations.  There may not be much demand -- or purpose -- for very large, very fast devices, because package strays dominate their performance.  SiC are widely available in traditional, high-inductance packages like TO-247, or brick modules; GaN is so fast, it's preposterous to place in such a package, and fortunately manufacturers have been wise enough to introduce them widely in DFN style packages.  The wide, short and low connections minimize transmission line impedance and length, minimizing losses (let alone outright destruction!) due to strays.  (They serve much the same purpose as traditional stripline RF transistor packages, but plastic DFNs are much cheaper than gold-plated metal and ceramic.)

In other words: for say a 10kW GaN converter, not only would it be impossible to try and use a 10mΩ chip at the ~ns risetime these devices are capable of, it's more efficient anyway to use many in parallel -- most likely not directly in parallel, but rather as independent channels working together such as a phase-interleave scheme.  This keeps the switching impedance (roughly speaking, the Vpk / Ipk at the switch) much more manageable.  (The effect of stray inductance and capacitance is relative to the switching impedance: consider Zstray = √(L/C) for loop inductance L and drain capacitance C.  Generally we want Zstray less than Zsw, and snubbing is required if Zstray is greater and t_stray = π √(LC)/2 is comparable to or greater than t_r.)

GaN also isn't yet widely available in higher voltages, whereas SiC has been steadily delivering parts in 1200 and 1700V ratings -- suitable for 100s of kW applications on 400/480V mains (industrial, solar, etc.) and EVs.  With more voltage headroom, more package inductance is tolerable, permitting much higher power levels per device/module.

Note that SiC modules may consist of multiple dies in parallel, so the device ratings again don't say anything about material capability or process yield; just that these are marketable solutions.

Comment: Very nice explanation and remarks :) thank you very much and sorry for my question which lacked of precision.

Answer (score 2):

As some comments have already pointed out, Rds(on) is just one parameter among others. It's similar to how you'd deal with reducing resistance in any circuit—by adding more MOSFETs in parallel.

Manufacturers sometimes go for a strategy where they increase the size of the transistor die to lower its resistance. But there's a catch. The larger size also leads to higher capacitance, making it a bit harder to control the transistor effectively.

Now, for a more meaningful comparison, you could consider the product of Qds and Rds(on), along with some other factors like Figures of Merit. This gives you a better overall picture since it takes into account the actual physical properties of the MOSFETs.

Anyway there are some differences between GaN and SiC and it's theoretical limits but the real characteristics of the transistors can vary a lot.

[image]

Source of the picture: [IEMN](https://www.iemn.fr/en/news/iemn-and-epigan-a-record-combination-of-specific-on-resistance-and-breakdown-voltage.html)

Comment: That picture says it all, the theoretical limit for the Rds(on) for GaN is lower than for SiC. We're probably not able to achieve it currently, but in the future GaN will probably be better than SiC in that regard, just like SiC and GaN are now compared to Si.

Comment: What chip area is used for those plots?

Comment: @winny none it's mOhm cm²

Comment: @Arsenal Ah! That explains it. Thanks.